# What are good resources to find jobs for those contemplating Aliya?

Tags: employment, aliya-laaretz

What are good resources to find jobs for those contemplating Aliya or for those that have made Aliya?

Comment: Why are we equating Zionism with Judaism?

Comment: What does making Aliya have to do with Zionism?

Comment: Aliyah has a lot to do with Zionism... (I am playing devil's advocate)

Comment: It also has alot to do with wanting to live in Eretz Yisroel.

Comment: Who said that the American Jewish Establishment should just pick up and move to E"Y?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Who said anything about the "American Jewish Establishment," about "should," or about "just pick up and move"?

Comment: Can I ask about resources to find jobs here in the U.S.?  If it is indeed a mitzvah to work, then perhaps it would be a good topic for a question.

Comment: Is this on-topic? It seems to be more of a "travel" or "workplace" question than Judaism

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, as moving to Israel is a religious imperative in Judaism, I would expect a community of experts on Judaism to be able to answer questions related to the particular challenges related to moving to Israel.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Boat programming?

Comment: @Shmuel, no, tefilin-painting

Answer (score 11):

There are 5 main avenues for finding a job in Israel.

### 1. LinkedIn

Many people in Israel use linkedIn and there are many Israel centric groups for all sorts of fields.  (Mostly related to "white collar" jobs)  There are few manual labor or blue collar jobs on LinkedIn but there are some.

### 2. Nefesh B'Nefesh's Employment Resources

These resources  will help you create networking opportunities and to find the people who know the people who can help you get you a job.  However they will not find you a job directly, they will only help you use the other 4 methods mentioned here. They can be a BIG help.  The NBN Facebook groups are also very helpful.

### 3. Headhunter groups.

Especially in the hightech field there are a number of companies who's job it is to find you job.  You do not always need good Hebrew skills to use these headhunting companies but it helps.

### 4. Janglo/Tanglo/etc.

There are a series of web groups called Janglo (Jeruselem Anglos) and Tanglo (Tel Aviv Anglos) and they have recently expanded to Haifa, The North, and the Negev.  This is a network for English speaking (Anglos) Israelis who are looking to help each other. They have websites and mailing lists and forums and all sorts of methods of finding jobs and employees.

### 5. Networking

Know someone, who knows someone who is aware of your skills and can give you job offers.  This is easier to do in Israel than you might think. 1. People are always wanting to help. 2. Most Israelis are shy when it comes to networking and know how hard it is. 3. The country is smaller and thus more people know more relevant people than they might in larger countries like the U.S.

Comment: +1, several times over. That said, it still really does depend on field, location, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[Nefesh b'Nefesh](http://www.nbn.org.il/aliyahpedia/employment-a-entrepreneurs.html) has some resources- how to obtain credentials, what companies are in your field, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Israemploy has a great [LinkedIn group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=73238&trk=anet_ug_hm), very active.
Though I would say that in the most part, the same resources that are good for looking for jobs are applicable to finding one in Israel, anyway, LinkedIn and personal networks chief among them.

Comment: P.S it also depends greatly on what type of job, what field, etc.